# Power BI Min date of each category

Tags: powerbi, dax

I am familiar with SQL and I can write a query to return results of a query to Select MIN(Date), MAX(Date), SUM(quality) and GROUP BY. However, I am new to Power BI and DAX and find it difficult to do the same on Power BI. Below is my situation.

These tables on Power BI:

Dim_ManefactureDate

[image]

Dim_ReleaseDate

[image]

Fact_OrderID

[image]

Table Relationships
[image]

Adding a table visualization to a new page to show data from three tables above, data is showing as below:
[image]

Under Values of Visualizations, when selecting SUM over Netweight, it automatically summarizes expected Netweight. However, for ManufactureDate and ReleaseDate, when selecting Earliest then Power BI table shows unexpected 1/01/1900 values like this:

[image]

I expect earliest date of each OrderID as below:

[image]

I have also tried to use a DAX function to create a new column but it gets error

```
ManufactureDate_Earliest = 
    VAR Sum_Netweight = SUM(Fact_OrderID[NetWeight])
    VAR GroupBy_OrderID = GROUPBY(Fact_OrderID,Fact_OrderID[OrderID])
    RETURN
        CALCULATE(
             MIN(RELATED(Dim_ManufactureDate[DateBK]))
            )
```

Thank you very much for your help

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Due to getting values from relationship tables, used these measured and solved the issue

```
ManufactureDate_Earliest = 
    CALCULATE(
        MIN(ManufactureDate[DateBK]),
        CROSSFILTER(Fact_Order[ManufactureDate_DateSK], ManufactureDate[DateSK], BOTH)
    )

ReleaseDate_Earliest = 
        CALCULATE(
            MIN(ReleaseDate[DateBK]),
            CROSSFILTER(Fact_Order[ReleaseDate_DateSK], ReleaseDate[DateSK], BOTH)
        )
```